# How can I automatically remove columns that are all null in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the basic SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
```

For a variety of reasons, there are entire columns of null values in this database. How can I augment this query to automatically return columns that are not all null? This will be performed in Oracle SQL Developer.

Thank you!

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL if you want to "dynamically" select columns.

Comment: Could you please explain what this is for?

Comment: I am trying to develop a tool for my coworkers where they can specify a specific study id (which will manifest itself as where study_id = 'abc ' in the query), but the problem is that the database is structured in such a way that I need a pivot table to rearrange the data from row form to column form. However, depending upon which study_id the user selects will determine which columns are created in the pivot table (some properties are unique to specific studies). My solution is to pivot all 15 unique properties, which will create some null columns depending upon which study_id is chosen.

Comment: So I would like to remove the null value columns which will then solve the entire problem.

Comment: SELECT propa,propb,propc,propd,prope,propf,VALUE_TEXT 
FROM tablename
PIVOT( 
  MAX(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)
   FOR ATTRIBUTE_NAME IN (
    'a' AS propa,
    'b' AS propb,
    'c' AS propc,
    'd' AS propd,
    'e' AS prope,
    'f' AS propf))
WHERE study_id = 'abc'

Comment: The problem arises when 'f' is not present in Attribute_name when study_id = 'abc', then propf will be a column of null values. How do I remove this?

Answer (score 0):

To do that you'll have to specify the columns, like this:

SELECT col1, col2, col5 FROM tablename

Comment: This will work, but is there a way to do this without knowing beforehand which columns will contain null values? Need an automated process.

Comment: (meaning, you can't really do it automatically in any simple way. If you *really* need to do it automatically, it's doable, but not through a simple SQL query)

Comment: Yes, it's doable but  I think you'd have to first query to count all the nulls in each column; then use the result to craft the query. It'll be fun but it isn't impossible.